# Javascript - Looping through an array of valid URL's

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I need some help with this for loop.. my code is supposed to run on these specific url's but It seems to skip over the loop and apply to all pages. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (isValidUrl()) {
        displayBoot();
        setupBootEvents();
    }
});

function isValidUrl() {
    var isValid = false,
        validUrls = [
            "/sport/btts-match-result", 
            "/sport/double-delight",
            "/sport/recently-paid-out",
            "/promotions",
            "/promotions/Sports",
            "/lotto",
            "/virtual", 
            "/bingo" 
        ];
    for (var i in validUrls) {
        var currentUrl = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
        if (currentUrl == validUrls[i]) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    //return isValid;
    return true;
}

function displayBoot() {...

function setupBootEvents() {...
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). After you've fixed your code, you will check, what you're actually comparing. Use console to show the values of `currentUrl` and `validUrls[i]`.

Comment: If `validUrl()` always returns `true`, why even check for that?

Comment: None of the URLs in the lookup has a search term so why would you need  to concatenate `+ window.location.search`?

Comment: And don't use `in` to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function a bit

```
function isValidUrl() {
        validUrls = [
            "/sport/btts-match-result", 
            "/sport/double-delight",
            "/sport/recently-paid-out",
            "/promotions",
            "/promotions/Sports",
            "/lotto",
            "/virtual", 
            "/bingo" 
        ];
    for (var i in validUrls) {
        var currentUrl = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
        if (currentUrl == validUrls[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And when working with the `location` object, always test in at least one Webkit-based and one Gecko-based browser.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I guess its fine fine in that case as well.. http://jsfiddle.net/hs8tqxyb/

Comment: @void, you missed the point. The OP's validUrls don't have search terms.

Comment: That depends on him, right? What if `validUrl` is just the `sample` not the whole `dataset`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70910/discussion-between-void-and-roamer-1888).